# Add a New Row to DataGrid when user press Enter Key on the last Cell of Last Row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid having 3 columns.

I want to add a new row to DataGrid when user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the last cell of DataGrid. I have successfully done everything as required using `DataGrid.InputBindings`, But the problem here is that when I presss <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on 2nd Column, a new row is added. I want it to be added when focus is on a cell which belong's to 3rd column and I press enter.

Here is my code :

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" CurrentCell="{Binding SelectedCell, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
          DataGridCell.GotFocus="DataGrid_CellGotFocus" SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DataContext.NewRowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Confirmation" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedConfirmation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                              Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ConfirmationVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <ComboBox.Items>
                            <sys:String>Add New</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>End Of List</sys:String>
                        </ComboBox.Items>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Age" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And In View-Model :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        People.Add(new Person());

        NewRowCommand = new RelayCommand(NewRow);

    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            return _people;
        }
        set
        {
            _people = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("People");
        }
    }

    private Person _selectedRow;
    public Person SelectedRow
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedRow;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedRow = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");

            if (_selectedRow == People.Last())
            {
                ConfirmationVisibility = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ConfirmationVisibility = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _confirmationVisibility;
    public bool ConfirmationVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _confirmationVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            _confirmationVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ConfirmationVisibility");
        }
    }

    private string _selectedConfirmation;
    public string SelectedConfirmation
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedConfirmation;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedConfirmation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedConfirmation");
        }
    }

    private DataGridCellInfo _selectedCell;
    public DataGridCellInfo SelectedCell
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCell;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCell = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCell");
        }
    }

    public ICommand NewRowCommand { get; set; }

    private void NewRow(object obj)
    {
        if (SelectedRow == People.Last())
        {
            if (SelectedConfirmation == "Add New")
            {
                if (SelectedCell.Column.Header.ToString() == "Age")
                {
                    People.Add(new Person());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Sample Project created in VS2012 : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bWVNHcVFXU1hOQ00/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code is with the CurrentCell property binding.
it binds the new current cell before NewRowCommand is called.

Lets assume you where on "Name" column on the last row, so what happens is:

1. You press the enter key.
2. Current cell is updated with the new cell. (Age)
3. **Then** your command is called, and uses the the new current cell(Age) and therefore adds new row.

I would suggest keeping a reference to the previous cell upon currentcell update. and using it instead of currentCell.

```
 public DataGridCellInfo SelectedCell
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCell;
        }
        set
        {
            _lastCell = _selectedCell; //here is my edit
            _selectedCell = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCell");
        }
    }
```

So the new NewRow(object obj) looks like this:

```
 private void NewRow(object obj)
    {
        if (SelectedRow == People.Last())
        {
            if (SelectedConfirmation == "Add New")
            {
                if (_lastCell.Column !=null && _lastCell.Column.Header.ToString() =="Age")//here is my edit
                {
                    People.Add(new Person());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also there is a problem inside DataGrid_CellGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e). take a look at my edit, i dropped the row.IsSelected assinment.

```
 private void DataGrid_CellGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Lookup for the source to be DataGridCell
        if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell))
        {
            // Starts the Edit on the row;
            DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;
            grd.BeginEdit(e);

            Control control = GetFirstChildByType<Control>(e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell);
            if (control != null)
            {
                control.Focus();
            }

            DataGridCell cell = GetDataGridCell(grd.CurrentCell);
            DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
            if (dataGrid != null)
            {
                if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
                {
                    if (!cell.IsSelected)
                        cell.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I ran the edited code on my pc, it works great! let me know if there are any issues I might have missed.

Comment: My problem is solved from the answer given by @klugerama. But There I get only one problem. Problem is : When a new row is added to the datagrid, the cell (that has focus just before the new row is added) does not leave edit mode even after it has lost its focus. I have tried the `DataGrid_CellGotFocus` from your code, but the result is still same.

Comment: Saw your other post on the edit mode after losing focus. This impl change does not cause this edit problem.

Comment: Sorry to say but I think I have implemented the changes very clearly as you suggested but still I have got that edit problem. If you does not get that edit problem any more, then please submit your sample project.

Comment: Its your sample project, modified with the changes I made https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6837746_80955217_394537

Answer (score 2):

Any `UIElement` can have `InputBindings`, not just `DataGrid`. So why not move

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DataContext.NewRowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

To the column you would like:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Age" Width="*">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}">
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DataContext.NewRowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}">
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DataContext.NewRowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>
                </TextBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I have tried the solution you provided. But still I get the same result.

Comment: I kept a breakpoint and took a close look at it. The problem here is that when I press enter on a cell in 2nd column, NewRowCommand is getting invoked. I think, Computer thinks that I pressed Enter key on a cell in 3rd Column.

Comment: And you *removed* the `InputBindings` at the `DataGrid` level?

Comment: Can you please verify it in sample provided by me?

Comment: You also have that `EnterKeyTraversal` class that is catching the `Enter` key. I found that removing the reference in 'MainWindow.xaml' fixed the problem with it being caught in column 2, but of course no longer moves to the next cell. Clean up the eventing so that you don't have multiple handlers.

Comment: If I clean up the eventing then I will not get required functionality.

Comment: OK, but `EnterKeyTraversal` is firing its events first (if focus is in the second column); it then moves the focus to the next column, which also then catches the `Enter` keypress because of the `InputBindings`.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: I have got it. I used PreviewKeyUp instead of PreviewKeyDown Event. But I have a slight problem. When new row is added to the datagrid the focus goes to next row as expected. But the current cell just before the new row was added remains in edit mode. Do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

When You Press enter then it instantly travels to 3rd column also So instead of creating column when you Selected header == Age create it when it equals Confirmation.
Here is your modified working code to fix the error

```
private void NewRow(object obj)
{
    if (SelectedRow == People.Last())
    {
        if (SelectedConfirmation == "Add New")
        {
            if (SelectedCell.Column.Header.ToString() == "Confirmation")
            {
                People.Add(new Person());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just do this and your sample worked with new row being created when user presses enter on last column.
Hope you got your problem solved and earned myself my first answer and points also.